# Error while using group by

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

In  table A I have the dates, and in B I have the order numbers.
In both tables I have a common field called order Id.
I just have a simple goal to fetch the number of orders on each date[ as in 1st, 2nd ..]
Here is what I have tried as I dont want to use joins or views.

```
select 
A.date_of_order,
count(B.order_number)
from A, B
where A.order_id=B.order_id;
group by A.date_of_order
```

I am getting the following error. Probably making some trivial error. Thanks in advance
Update:
After taking into consideration Dmitri and rafa s suggestions, I get the table as:

```
23-FEB-14   1
23-FEB-14   1
23-FEB-14   2
23-FEB-14   2
23-FEB-14   2
07-MAR-14   2
07-MAR-14   4
07-MAR-14   1
07-MAR-14   5
02-MAR-14   1
02-MAR-14   1
```

As I said my requirement is very simple, just get it as

```
23-Feb-14 10[i.e. all the orders placed on this date]
07-Mar-14 13
02-mar-14 2
```

Comment: Why no joins? That's what they're made for. Either way, `WHERE` should go before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Out of interest: Am I correct in thinking that joins join the rows where the condition is met while WHERE selects all the records and after that applies the filter?

Comment: You **are** using a join in that query. It's just the old-fashioned,  outdated implicit join in the where clause instead of an explicit `JOIN` clause

Comment: @matthijs: I think that could be a correct explanation of the *logical* order of processing. As for implementation, I believe most modern SQL products would translate a `FROM a, b WHERE x` to a corresponding `FROM a JOIN b ON x` internally and apply physical operators (scans, seeks, joins...) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

WHERE should be put *before* GROUP BY:

```
   select A.date_of_order,
          count(B.order_number)
     from A, B
    where A.order_id = B.order_id -- <- possible, but join will be better here
 group by A.date_of_order
```

If you want a condition *after* GROUP BY you should use HAVING

```
   select A.date_of_order,
          count(B.order_number)
     from A, B
    where A.order_id = B.order_id
 group by A.date_of_order
   having count(B.order_number) < 3 -- having demo
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt responses, but I still dont get it with single dates.I get like this: 23-FEB-14 2 23-FEB-14 2 23-FEB-14 2 07-MAR-14 2 07-MAR-14 4 07-MAR-14 1 02-MAR-14 1 02-MAR-14 1

Comment: @The Recruit: That is an expected result, because you're GROUP'ing BY date_of_order: you count order_number for each distinct date.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause must to be **before** of the `GROUP BY` clause.
Use `TRUNC(date)` to get rid of the time so the `GROUP BY` will work as expected.

```
SELECT TRUNC(A.date_of_order), COUNT(B.order_number)
FROM A, B
WHERE A.order_id=B.order_id
GROUP BY TRUNC(A.date_of_order)
```

Anyway it is recommended to use the [ANSI-standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) SQL `JOIN` clause instead.

```
SELECT TRUNC(A.date_of_order), COUNT(B.order_number)
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.order_id = B.order_id
-- (WHERE conditions here)
GROUP BY TRUNC(A.date_of_order)
-- (HAVING conditions here)
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt responses, but I still dont get it with single dates.I get like this: 23-FEB-14 2 23-FEB-14 2 23-FEB-14 2 07-MAR-14 2 07-MAR-14 4 07-MAR-14 1 02-MAR-14 1 02-MAR-14 1

Comment: Does exactly what the query does, group the orders by date. What do you want exactly to do? Can you update your question with a table of expected results so I can understand better your intention?

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons could be that

1) Dates have timestamp, in that case following query would be helpful:

```
select 
trunc(A.date_of_order),
count(B.order_number)
from A, B
where A.order_id=B.order_id
group by trunc(A.date_of_order);
```

2) Since in your sample data, you already have count against the dates, you need to take sum instead of count for your query

```
select 
A.date_of_order,
sum(B.order_number)
from A, B
where A.order_id=B.order_id
group by A.date_of_order;
```

3) Or could be both, in that case you can try

```
select 
trunc(A.date_of_order),
sum(B.order_number)
from A, B
where A.order_id=B.order_id
group by trunc(A.date_of_order);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to join to that other table at all. Try just running:

```
select date_of_order, count(order_id) from tbl_a group by date_of_order
```

Your question states that table A contains rows for each order ID and date, and all you want to do is count the number of orders by date.